# What reverse engineering means in this article from msdn?

Tags: entity-framework-6, code-first, reverse-engineering

I was trying to study entity framework's code first approach with an existing database. I've understood most part of this article from msdn.

Article URL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx .

Under the "What if My Database Changes?" section at the bottom of the article, it said

"The Code First to Database wizard is designed to generate a starting point set of classes that you can then tweak and modify. If your database schema changes you can either manually edit the classes or perform another reverse engineer to overwrite the classes."

I could not understand how to perform another reverse engineer, does it mean I need to delete the context & all other model class which were created & create them again? I believe there is a smarter work around. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That means you need to update your models either by updating it or editing them manually.

Comment: How can I update my models without manually editing them. I want to change the database table and I want my models to be updated. How can I do that?

Comment: well just update/regenate your edmx.

Comment: well, with code first approach You don't have any edmx. Rather I have a context class which inherits from the DBContext class and model class for every database table.

Comment: If you don't have a database then you create models and contexts to create it, but if you have an existing database you can easily generate the edmx.

Comment: I know, but maintaining edmx seems to be a headache when the number of tables is really high. It takes a lot of time to update the edmx. I heard that with code first approach with an existing database, the models get auto updated during the initialization of the  project whenever there is a change in the database.

Comment: How do you think that works, with out any logical connection between the database and your models?

Comment: Probably I need to tweak something in the constructor of my context class which will tell the context class to sync with the targeted database before creating the instance. I'm looking for that.

Comment: You can create custom database initializers, please see if that suffise your concern(s).

Comment: This is what they meant by reverse engineering. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d